# Using zsh completion outside zsh

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

What is the best way to use zsh completion outside zsh? I know that I can redefine compadd builtin with custom function and parse its options, but is there a better way?

I want to add omni completion for shell scripts to Vim based on zsh completion system.

Comment: Dear $DEITY, please tell me you know how to do this. I'd love to have zstyles everywhere.

Comment: @chiggsy All I know that if I spend a lot of time writing hacks that override various built-in commands (one `compadd` is not enough) and reimplementing functionality that is done by them I could do the job. It is not something I'm willing to spend time on.

Comment: So... Clarification question: Am I understanding you correctly to think that you're asking for some way to access the interactive completion system of zsh from, e.g., the command prompt within vim?  That seems... like vim would need to be modified to link to it... perhaps it can be bulled out as a library, that zsh and vim could both use??

Comment: @lindes. If there is a C library that provides access to completion then python module can be created that interacts with this library and a vimL+python plugin that interacts with this module, so there is no need to modify vim. Apparently, there is no such library and no “standart” way to do this, though splitting zsh into zle library suitable for creating custom shells (with overriding completion variants displaying function, of course) and UI would be definitely welcome, as it can be used not to just get the completion variants, but as a much better replacement to readline.

Comment: @ZyX: That sounds like something that would be very nice indeed.  I hope that you and/or others find the energy to make it happen.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This same question was asked on the zsh mailing list on 23 Aug 2004: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2004/msg00917.html. At least I believe it's the same question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Basically, the bash shell uses [readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) for its line-editing, but zsh [uses its own and more powerful zle](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh).

This question asks if zle can be used for input for a command line program instead of having to write it from scratch.

There are 2 replies to this question. One says:

"This is actually relatively easy to do.  For a working example, see
Functions/Misc/nslookup in the zsh distribution."

The other reply is from the original asker and it says:

"If just 'preexec' could access BUFFER, writing the edited command
line could be written anywhere, but since BUFFER is only accessible
inside completion widgets, this should be done with a widget,
replacing 'accept-line' or something like that."

Hopefully this helps.